# Woocommerce change in stock text by category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter, product

So how a title says, I have a multiple product "test" website. And each product have **" X in stock "** in shop page.
My website is filtred by category like **"Floors" and "Blinds".**

And my question is how to I change and text **" X in stock "** to imagine **"X Boxes in Stock"**. I want a simple solution to don't affect another products category.

Like Floor's category display: **"X Boxes in Stock"**
And Blind's category display: **"X Meters in Stock"**

Something like that.

Thank you~!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check it with this code

```
function ak_woocommerce_get_availability( $availability, $product ) {
    // Specific categories
    $specific_categories = array( 'test', 'test-1' );
    
       
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() && has_term( $specific_categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('My custom text', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $availability;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'ak_woocommerce_get_availability', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I have tryed and working in single page :). I will try and follow this rules seems legit thank you! How I can adapt this code to show in the main shop page?

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'xstore_stock_catalog', 10 );
    function xstore_stock_catalog() {
        global $product;
        if ( $product->is_in_stock() && has_term( 'rodapes', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            echo '<div class="et-stock" >' .  $availability['availability'] = $product->get_stock_quantity() . __( '   Rodapés', 'woocommerce' ) . '</div>';   } 
        }
```

This worked for me :)